# Getting Rid of Decimals in Ticker Formatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use the Ticker library to add percents and dollar signs to my graph, it automatically adds decimals that I don't want.  Any idea how to get rid of these?  Here is a snippet of my code.

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 13, 2))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 501, 50))
yticks = ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()
yticks[0].label1.set_visible(False)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
formatter = mtick.FormatStrFormatter('$%1.2f')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for decimals:

```
formatter = mtick.FormatStrFormatter('$%1.2f')
```

The part behind the dot in `%1.2f` specifies the number of decimals, the number before the dot gives the minimum width of the output. For the simplest case `%.0f` should be sufficient.

The PercentFormatter has a parameter `decimals` to control the number of places:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(decimals=0))
```